# Riverpod provider list updates from firebase only if the code is in the provider

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, riverpod

I have a Riverpod Streamprovider that manages how a number of different Firebase documents are presented to the user.  The user can then access each document, make some changes and return to the list of their documents.  Once they have made, changes the row for that document should have a tick showing. The only wrinkle is that these documents in a different collection, each with their own identifier.  So its not as easy as just streaming a whole collection, my function needs to get the identifier for each item and then get a list of documents to send to the user.

I have the code so it 'just works' but what I can't work out is why updating the record works when all the code is inside the provider vs when the provider calls it a external code.  For example this StreamProvider works as I want and updated documents are recognised

```
final outputStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose((ref) async* {
  final List<itemModelTest> itemList = [];
  final user = ref.watch(loggedInUserProvider);
  final uid = ref.watch(authStateProvider).value!.uid;
  for (String ident in user.value!.idents) {

# get each item by its own identifier

    final item = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('items')
        .where("ident", isEqualTo: ident)
        .limit(1)
        .snapshots();
    final result = await item.first;
    final test = result.docs[0];
    final itemItem = itemModelTest.fromFirebaseQuery(test, uid);
    itemList.add(itemItem);

# Listen for changes in the items

    item.listen((event) async {
      dev.log('event changed');
      for (var change in event.docChanges) {
        if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.modified) {
          itemModelTest updatedModel =
              itemModelTest.fromFirebaseQuery(test, uid);
          itemList
              .removeWhere((element) => element.title == updatedModel.title);
          itemList.add(updatedModel);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  yield itemList;
});
```

But as you can see it contains a lot of logic that doesn't belong there and should be with my firebase database class.  So I tried to split it so now in my firebase crud class I have almost identical code:

```
Stream<List<itemModelTest>> itemsToReviewStream(LoggedInUser user, String uid) async*{
  final List<itemModelTest> itemList = [];
  for (String ident in user.idents) {
    final item = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('items')
        .where("ident", isEqualTo: ident)
        .limit(1)
        .snapshots();
    final result = await item.first;
    final test = result.docs[0];
    final itemItem = itemModelTest.fromFirebaseQuery(test, uid);
    itemList.add(itemItem);


    item.listen((event) async {
      dev.log('event changed ${event.docChanges.first.doc}');
      for(var change in event.docChanges){
        if(change.type == DocumentChangeType.modified){
          itemModelTest updatedModel = itemModelTest.fromFirebaseQuery(test, uid);
          itemList.removeWhere((element) => element.title == updatedModel.title);
          itemList.add(updatedModel);
        }
      }
    });
  }yield itemList;
}
```

and my StreamProvider now looks like this

```
// Get a list of the currently logged in users papers to review
final testitemStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose((ref)  {
  final user = ref.watch(loggedInUserProvider).value;
  final uid = ref.watch(authStateProvider).value!.uid;
  return DataBase().itemsToReviewStream(user!, uid);
});
```

The only problem is using this second approach the updates to firebase don't trigger any updates to the ui so when the user returns to their list of documents they cant see which have been processed already.  I have been round the houses trying to work out what I am doing wrong but cant see it.

Edit: just a quick edit in case it matters but this is for FlutterWeb not iOS or Android

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving this in case anyone else has the same problem.  The real problem with this project was that the database structure was not fit for purpose and a further restriction was to not duplicate data on the database.

The simplest solution (and if you happen to be reading this because you fixing a similar problem) is to make a copy of the documents the user is supposed to have access to in their own collection, this can then be streamed as an entire collection.  Checking which documents have and have not been looked at by users was always going to have to be done via an admin account anyway, so it's not as though this would have incurred a penalty.

All the same to manage my particular data repo i ended up

1 make a simple provider to stream a single document

```
 final getSinglePageProvider = StreamProvider.family((ref, String  pageId){
   return DataBase().getSinglePage(pageId);});
```

Then once you have a list of all the documents the user has access to make a provider that provides a list of providers above

```
final simpleOutputsStreamsProvier = StreamProvider((ref) async* {
  final user = ref.watch(loggedInUserProvider);
  final items = user.value!.items;
  yield items.map((e) => ref.watch(getSinglePageProvider(e))).toList();
});
```

You can then use this in a consumer as normal, but it has to be 'consumed' twice.  In my case, I watched the ListProvider in the build method of a ConsumerWidget. That gives you a list of StreamProviders for individual pages.  Finally I used ListView to get each StreamProvide (listofProviders[index]) and unwrapped that with provider.when(...

I have no idea how brittle this approach will turn out to be however!